# Заполнение списка в одной Activity из другой Activity

Tags: java

Пытаюсь сделать такой интерфейс: что бы пользователь тапал на кнопку "Добавить", и перед ним появлялись `ImageView` - на какой `ImageView` он кликнет, тот добавиться на предыдущий `Activity` (где расположена кнопка "Добавить").

Как сделать передачу `ImageView` из одного активити в другое, и при этом возможность сохранять и очищать переданное `ImageView`?

И еще как сделать так, чтобы каждый новый добавленный `ImageView` выстраивался в список? Пример интерфейса можно увидеть на скриншотах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас тут три вопроса в одном, по-хорошему это должны быть три разных вопроса. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых, `ImageView` здесь недостаточен, так как отображаемые у вас данные разнородны (картинка, текст) и часть их них динамическая (вес и повторы могут меняться). Здесь нужна более сложная организация данных, например - класс-модель. Кроме того, выбранные тренировки, скорее всего должны сохранятся между запусками, чтобы не вводить все каждый раз заново - здесь нужна БД.

Поскольку вопрос очень общий и писать за вас вашу программу я не испытываю желания, то ограничимся общими же рекомендациями по организации такого функционала:

1. Нужно создать БД, в которой организовать таблицу со всеми возможными упражнениями. Она будет содержать собственный `id` каждого упражнения,  `id` картинки и текст с описанием упражнения (короткий и полный) - эта таблица постоянна и не изменяется.
2. Нужно создать еще одну таблицу, с текущими выбранными упражнениями. Она будет динамически меняться в зависимости от выбора пользователя и будет содержать `id` упражнения и текущие параметры веса и повторов.
3. Теперь вам нужно написать класс для взаимодействия с БД, который будет отдавать все записи из второй таблицы и включать туда данные из первой, а так же позволять добавлять удалять и изменять их. Для удобства работы отдавать данные класс должен в виде объекта-модели, который на выходе будет содержать: `id` картинки, название тренировки, заданный вес и количество повторов. Все это упаковывается в какой то контейнер, например коллекцию `ArrayList`.
4. Теперь нужно написать адаптер, который будет по данным полученным в пункте 3 коллекции, содержащих  классы-модели, заполнять список.
5. Создаем собственную разметку для каждого пункта (айтема). Указываем размещение картинки и текстов.
6. В первой активити размещаем виджеты для вывода подготовленных данных: кнопки добавить\редактировать и `ListView` для вывода списка тренировок.
7. Логика первой активити устроена так, чтобы через адаптер пункта 4 выводить в `ListView` с айтемами, созданными в пункте 5, список таблицы 2, преобразованный к нужному виду классом из пункта 3.
8. Логика второй активити построена так, чтобы добавлять в таблицу 2 выбранный пункт из таблицы 1 (само упражнение) и  данные о повторах и весе.
9. Все по основным моментам.

Более подробно ответить на ваш вопрос в таком виде, как он оформлен сейчас не получится, так как это надо написать за вас всю программу. Начните делать и задавайте КОНКРЕТНЫЕ вопросы по проблемам, а не общие по организации и логике работы, тогда помощь будет предметной.